# Editing a .txt file with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Alright, I've looked around and tried to adapt some of the code I did find to make it work but all attempts I've tried have failed.

Basically I have a text file, we'll call it TEST.txt

TEXT.txt contains these three lines:

```
Var1=test1
Var2=test2
Var3=test3
```

Basically I am trying to get a batch file to ask me what I want to change the value of var3 to and then change the value of var3 to reflect what I typed in.

Is this possible?  If so how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show any of the attempts that you've tried?  Maybe someone may steer you into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%a iN (var2change var2change2) DO SET "%%a="
SET /p var2change="Change which variable ? "
SET /p var2change2="Change %var2change% to ? "


ECHO Values before
TYPE q24373191.txt
ECHO =============
:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('type q24373191.txt') DO (
 IF /i "%%a"=="%var2change%" (ECHO %%a=%var2change2%
 ) ELSE (ECHO %%a=%%b
 )
)
)>"%tempfile%a"

COPY /y /b "%tempfile%a" q24373191.txt >nul
DEL "%tempfile%a"

ECHO Values after
TYPE q24373191.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q24373191.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it. It is quite simple

```
set /p lol=what do you want var3 to be?: 
echo Var1=test1 >> test.txt
echo Var2=test2 >> test.txt
echo Var1=%lol% >> test.txt
```

Lol.