# Batch file write to txt

Tags: sqlite, batch-file, parameters

I want to make a batch file that will ask user for input, than write that input to a specific position in an already written txt file(called commands.txt which contains query) and call sqlite3 < commands.txt
I need this so inside the commands.txt where the query is, in LIKE 'userinput' i will add the users choice (parameter)

Comment: OK. Go ahead and make that batch file. We'll wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is not really specific enough and verging on the kind of inappropriate question that for stackoverflow (it does not include code), as hinted at by the comment, I'll take it at face value and assume there is much you need help with.

First let me deal with the question "I need to make a batch file"

A batch file is a simple text file with the extension `.bat`. You can create it with a text editor like notepad. We do not know what kind of system you have (Windows, linux, Mac etc) but lets assume Windows as you asked for a batch file. We do not know which version of windows (7 or 8 etc), So I'll try and be generic.

All windows machines come with a simpe text file editor called notepad. You can open this by typing notepad  into the search box on windows 7 or 8. Lets start with a simple batch file:

```
:: This is a batch file
@echo off
echo Hello World
exit /b
```

Type (or paste) those 4 lines into notepad. Now select the *file* menu and select *Save As*, now in the *Save As Type:* selector choose *All Files*. In the *File name:* box type the desired name with the bat extension, such as `doit.bat`. Ensure you choose a suitable directory to place your new batch file. Leave the encoding as ASCII. Click Save. You have now made your first batch file.

Now you need to execute that batch file. Using the Windows File Explorer find the folder where you saved that batch file. While viewing the folder, hold down the shift key on the keyboard and then right click in the background of the folder and select *Open Command window here*. You will now have a command prompt window. You can now execute your new batch file by typing its name `doit`. It will display:

```
Hello World
```

OK - Now you have created your first working batch file.

Now for the next part; Asking the user for input. This is done with the `set /p` command. Add this to your batch file (before the exit line):

```
Set /P Like="Give me your input: "
echo Your input was: %Like%
```

That has solved the second part. Now the third part, edit the commands.txt file. If you do an internet search for a similar problem (editing files in batch files) you might find this help page: http://www.ousob.com/ng/edlin/ng96d9.php. This shows a generic way of changing any text string  to any other in a file using EDLIN from a batch file; unfortunately EDLIN (and EDIT) are no longer included in windows so these batch files are not much help.

A search of stackoverflow finds [similar queries which contain an answer for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373191/editing-a-txt-file-with-a-batch-file).

So now you have all the parts of the answer:

1. How to make a batch file
2. How to prompt the user for input
3. How to replace lines of text in the commands.txt

You should be able to put it together and get it to work....

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help me for sure